# gradle configurations/artifacts only uses "default" configuration

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

submodule **(locallibs)** build.gradle looks like the following:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('defaultdistro.aar'))
configurations.create("distro2")
artifacts.add("distro2", file('distro2.aar'))
configurations.create("distro3")
artifacts.add("distro3", file('distro3.aar'))
```

the build.gradle for the app has a dependencies{} section that looks like the following:

```
dependencies {
    debugCompile project(':locallibs')
    flavor1ReleaseCompile project(path: ':locallibs', configuration: 'distro2')
    flavor2ReleaseCompile project(path: ':locallibs', configuration: 'distro3')
}
```

The issue I'm having is that regardless of the flavor/build type the "default" configuration is always compiled so all of my flavors are including the "defaultdistro.aar" instead of the correct .aar distro.

I am expecting for flavor1 release build type to compile the distro2.aar but *all* flavors are compiling the defaultdistro.aar

EDIT: fixed the locallibs build.gradle representation

EDIT #2: the .aar distros are mutually exclusive

Comment: it's the only line that uses artifacts.add instead of configurations.add, is there a reason that one is different?

Comment: @ootinii i have updated the question. copy/paste error, I apologize.

Comment: if you remove the default creation, configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('defaultdistro.aar')), what happens then? wondering if maybe default is considered a special configuration

Comment: for case where there is a configurations.create("default") but no artifacts.add("default", file("xxxx")) then no .aar are compiled so the references cause compile time errors indicating that "class not found" or "package does not exist"

if the "default" config is not added at all then gradle throws "Configuration with name 'default' not found"